# can't decode a urlencoded utf-8 string

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, multibyte

Here's the string:

```
%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%b7
```

I think it's cyrillic and I need it converted to something readable.

[`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) states it's ASCII.

When I do `iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $str)`, it shows me the same string.

Judging by [this article](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), looks like it's in UTF-8, but how do I decode that into readable UTF?

Please help

**UPDATE** the following site was able to decode the text: http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en (thanks to Faiz Rasool for pointing out). The preset I used there is `source=utf-8; postfilter=urlencoded`, but I've no idea how to reproduce that on my server.

Answer (score 1):

This string look like url encoded try this.

```
<?php
$str = "%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%b7";
echo utf8_encode(urldecode($str));
?>
```

Comment: thank you, url-decoding was the first thing i've tried, didn't work

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica this is the output Без

Comment: thank you for the link, right, the option that works is `urlencoded::utf-8`

Comment: Ok, thank you, you got a deserved upvote, but this still doesn't help, sorry. Your sample outputs `ÐÐµÐ·` which is not `Без`. I agree, the link you've shared is able to decode the text, but I've no idea how did they do that